# How to use WebM file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webm

Because GIF file is really heavy, I want to use WebM file instead of Gif file. However, VS Code can't read WebM file and the Flutter also can't read the file.

Therefore, if I run the Flutter project, it shows the error that `Exception: Invalid image data`. How can I fix this problem and what's the best way to use WebM file instead of GIF file?

This is the code that I used:

```
child: Image.asset(
  // (note.getCategoryName() == Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_NAME_DIET)
  //     ? 'assets/ani_give_coffee_diet.gif'
  //     : (note.getCategoryName() == Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_NAME_EXERCISE)
  //         ? 'assets/ani_give_coffee_exercise.gif'
  //         : 'assets/ani_give_coffee_diet.gif',
  (note.getCategoryName() ==
          Constants
              .TAG_CATEGORY_NAME_EXERCISE)
      ? 'assets/ani_give_coffee_exercise.webm'
      : 'assets/ani_give_coffee_diet.webm',
),
```

Comment: Have you tried using a video player? Webm is a video format.

Comment: I want to use it but it shows error that Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:video_player/video_player.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

Answer (score 0):

If not necessary, instead of using WebM or gif, try using WebP image format that is smaller in size and now supported by iOS and Android. The method is same as other image formats.

```
child: Image.asset(
  (note.getCategoryName() ==
          Constants
              .TAG_CATEGORY_NAME_EXERCISE)
      ? 'assets/ani_give_coffee_exercise.webp'
      : 'assets/ani_give_coffee_diet.webp',
),
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried WebP file, and it reduces 80% of the size of the original file. However, it has a little bit of buffering and it's kind of annoying. That's why I decided to use WebM

Comment: If buffering is an issue, you can try [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html). [Here](https://educity.app/flutter/the-right-way-to-preload-or-precache-images-in-flutter-for-extreme-fast-rendering) is a tutorial to use `precachedImage`.

Answer (score 0):

video player cannot play webm urls, you can use vlc player

Answer (score -1):

First, install the [`video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package.

Then, try the following code:

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(note.getCategoryName() == Constants.TAG_CATEGORY_NAME_EXERCISE) ? 'assets/ani_give_coffee_exercise.webm' : 'assets/ani_give_coffee_diet.webm')
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});
  });

  _controller.setLooping(true);

  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();

  super.dispose();
}
```

---

```
_controller.value.isInitialized
  ? AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
    )
  : Container(),
```

Comment: I will try it and I will let you know. Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Hi! Did you use Stateful widget? The flutter says that "Non-nullable instance field '_controller' must be initialized."

Comment: Yes, I use `StatefulWidget`

Comment: I used your code but it only shows Container(). Also, vscode can't show the WebM file because it can't read.

Comment: The vscode says that "the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.", so it can't shows the webm file

Comment: I edited. Also, maybe it's only readable by VS Code. See if it can be read by Flutter

Comment: Ummm maybe it's not readable bt VS code. I guess VS code and flutter don't support WebM file. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Does my code work?

Comment: Sadly no :( It only shows empty Container()